# Sorting huge volumed data using Serialized Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, performance, sorting, serialization, binary-search-tree

I have 50 GB structured (as key/value) data like this which are stored in a text file (input.txt / keys and values are 63 bit unsigned integers);

```
3633223656935182015 2473242774832902432
8472954724347873710 8197031537762113360
2436941118228099529 7438724021973510085
3370171830426105971 6928935600176631582
3370171830426105971 5928936601176631564
```

I need to sort this data as keys in increasing order with the minimum value of that key. The result must be presented in another text file (data.out) under 30 minutes. For example the result must be like this for the sample above;

```
2436941118228099529 7438724021973510085
3370171830426105971 5928936601176631564
3633223656935182015 2473242774832902432
8472954724347873710 8197031537762113360
```

I decided that;

- I will create a BST tree with the keys from the input.txt with their minimum value, but this tree would be more than 50GB. I mean, I have time and memory limitation at this point.
- So I will use another text file (tree.txt) and I will serialize the BST tree into that file.
- After that, I will traverse the tree using in-order traverse and write the sequenced data into data.out file.

My problem is mostly with the serialization and deserialization part. How can I serialize this type of data? and I want to use the INSERT operation on the serialized data. Because my data is bigger than memory. I can't perform this in the memory. Actually I want to use text files as a memory.

By the way, I am very new to this kind of stuffs. If is there a conflict with my algorithm steps, please warn me. Any thought, technique and code samples would be helpful.

```
OS: Linux
Language: C
RAM: 6 GB
```

Note: I am not allowed to use built-in functions like sort and merge.

Comment: Personally, I'd split the file into (maybe 100) smaller files with `split`, sorting each of them (`sort`) and finally, write or find a program able to merge sorted files into one.

Comment: The fact that you have 6GB RAM may not prevent from have bigger data structures. If your OS supports virtual memory 50GB should be OK (Think about all the heavy video games which consume much more than the available RAM). If you want to use the file as a memory I would recommend you to read about `mmap`. It is just what you are looking. http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap Here is the link to the example: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-system-programming/0596009585/ch04s03.html

Comment: Treesort is a bad choice; it needs an overhead of at least two pointers per record (half of them NULL). Mergesort would be the obvious choice, or maybe a radix sort variant. Or: use a database and go for a walk. BTW: mmap() seems like a very bad choice, too, (because the locality of reference is not guaranteed, more than half of the reads would result in pagefaults)

Comment: Does the double `3370171830426105971` key in input, missing from output, mean that duplicate keys overwrite previous entries? If so, you should emphasize this because it further complicates the problem.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe there might be some duplicate keys but, my program should be select the key with the minimum value. Thus, data.out shouldn't have any duplicate key.

Comment: @Marian How should I define the split size? Why don't you split it as 4GB instead of 100 MB?

Comment: @Erdiİzgi just count lines in your file with `wc`, then do a `split -l maxlines yourfile`. I would chose the number of lines per file in a way, that you can easily store and sort each file in memory and that the resulting number of files is not too big. 1000 files seems a reasonable limit to me.

Comment: Looks like a k-way merge sort would be needed for the external sort. The initial pass could use counting  radix sort to create 2GB runs. A 25 way bottom up merge external sort could sort in one pass afterwards. Linux (and Windows) have 64 bit versions of fseek, which would eliminate the need for a large number of files. A pair of files would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Considering, that your files seems to have the same line size around 40 chars giving me around 1250000000 lines in total, I'd split the input file into smaller, by a command:

```
split -l 2500000 biginput.txt
```

then I'd sort each of them

```
for f in x*; do sort -n $f > s$f; done
```

and finally I'd merge them by

```
sort -m sx* > bigoutput.txt
```

Comment: There's no need to write merge yourself if you're allowed GNU sort. Simply use the `--merge` flag; it does the same thing, and should be compatible with `-n`. Edit: `-m` (the short form) is actually POSIX, it seems.

Comment: This seems correct but unfortunately I am not allowed to use built-in functions like sort and merge.